# Dark Vibrant Window containing NSTableView - Tune Background Color

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, background, nstableview

I set my window's appearance to `NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark` in order to have some kind of "dark" theme, which works wonderfully. Not being a fan of pure black though, I want to lighten the UI elements a little bit.

I set the window's background color to pure white, that made the toolbar look grey, which is perfect:

[image]

But in my window, I have a `NSTableView` that was not affected by this change:

[image]

As you see, everything is really dark and the alternating colors for the rows are barely visible. I want to lighten up this so I tried setting the `NSTableView` background color to white, it didn't help. I tried setting the enclosing `NSView` `CALayer`'s background color to white and this didn't help either (I specified that this view needed to have a layer with the `wantsLayer` property).

My most fortunate attempt was to implement `tableView(_: didAddRowView: forRow:)` and manually set the colors of the row views:

```
if row % 2 == 1 {
    rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 1)
} else {
    rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1)
}
```

BUT, this doesn't affect empty rows below my data, they remain very dark. I would like the empty rows to be the same color as the populated ones.

Thanks !

**NOTE**: I don't care about the header row background color, it can stay the current shade of grey.

Comment: Is the tableview inside a scrollview?

Comment: You can click on 'Debug View Hierarchy' in XCode and see which view is coloured, and then try changing the colour to that view.